# Add shadowPath to UITableView subclass

Tags: swift

I want to create a shadow on a subview on my UITableView:

```swift
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    mainBackground = UIView()
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    backgroundColor = .clear
               
    mainBackground.backgroundColor = .red
    mainBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    mainBackground.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
    contentView.addSubview(mainBackground)

    setupConstraints()
}
    
func setupConstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mainBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        mainBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
        mainBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        mainBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
    ])
}
```

I'm placing my shadow code in layoutSubviews, where I also use `UIEdgeInsets` to make my subview smaller:

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let margins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 8, bottom: 5, right: 8)
    contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: margins)
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    setupShadow()
}
    
public func setupShadow() {        
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.mainBackground.frame).cgPath
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Without the `shadowPath` this seems to work, but with it I don't get a shadow at all. I want to use a `shadowPath` to make the drawing of the shadow efficient. How do I add the `shadowPath` here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't quite understand what kind of result do you expect to achieve.

I don't think it's possible to get any kind of "shadow" for a UITableViewCell because usually shadows are outside/around the view, but table view cells stay next to each other, without any gap in between. So any shadow of the first cell will be overlapped by the second cell.

```
self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.mainBackground.frame).cgPath
```

here you add a shadow to the cell, but the shadow is overlapped by `mainBackgroundView` so the shadow is invisible

try that:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    mainBackground.backgroundColor = .red
    mainBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    
    mainBackground.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    mainBackground.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    mainBackground.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    mainBackground.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    
    contentView.addSubview(mainBackground)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    mainBackground.frame = contentView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)
    mainBackground.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.mainBackground.bounds).cgPath
}
```

and increase the height of your cells to ~100pt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    100
}
```

and you will be able to play with a shadow applied to `mainBackgroundView`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  var setupShadowDone: Bool = false
    
    public func setupShadow() {
        if setupShadowDone { return }
        print("Setup shadow!")
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, 
byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 
8)).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    
        setupShadowDone = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("Layout subviews!")
        setupShadow()
    }
```